# Formatting asynchronous tabs in TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a question about how to format a tkinter program that has to handle multiple tabs that run the same tasks with different input asynchronously?

Right now, I have one class that holds the entire application. Is there a better way to format my application?

I was thinking of putting each tab into a class, which would be in the application class but I'm not sure if is this the best way to do it, like so:

```
class Application():
    def __init__(self):
    #code

    class tab1():
        def __init__(self):
            #code

    class tab2():
        def __init__(self):
            #code
```

I am new to GUI programming so I applogize if this question is too broad.

Comment: You've given nowhere near enough details for a specific answer - and there's not likely to be one right answer anyway, this is largely a matter of personal style.  In any case, there's no need to put your tab classes INSIDE the Application class; that's pretty much pointless in Python.  If all of the tabs are functionally identical, you don't need a separate class for each one, just create multiple instances of a single class.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include some links to multiprocessing documentation and a stackoverflow question that seams to have the same kind of question you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see you have 2 problems related to this question.

One is the issue of have 3 separate tabs/widgets.

This is easy enough to accomplish. You can do this using 1 function with several variables that you are changing between each of your 3 processes and then call the function 3 times with those different variables.

```
def doStuff(var1, var2, var3):
    sumvars = var1 - var2 * var3
    return sumvars

print(doStuff(1,2,3), doStuff(3,2,1), doStuff(2,3,1))
```

Result:

```
-5 1 -1
```

As you can see this is 3 different processes ran from the same defined function

You can accomplish this with a class. You only need one class that has the variables in questions as arguments. You can call that class 3 different times with the different variables you need to have worked on.

```
class DoStuff(object):
    def __init__(self, var1, var2, var3):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
        self.var3 = var3

    def someMath(self):
        sumvars = self.var1 - self.var2 * self.var3
        return sumvars

object1 = DoStuff(1,2,3)
object2 = DoStuff(3,2,1)
object3 = DoStuff(2,3,1)

print(object1.someMath(), object2.someMath(), object3.someMath())
```

Result:

```
-5 1 -1
```

Update:

From my research you might want to take a look at multiprocessing library.

If you look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22700164/python-running-multiple-processes-simultaneously) there was a user with a similar problem and they discovered using the multiprocessing  library that each process does in fact have its own Process ID and is running in parallel from what I read.

Here is a link to the documentation on [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: You are welcome. if you take the time to read the post i linked they talk about about synchronous processing options. And if I have answered your question consider selecting this as your answer :)

Comment: Reading about it now, I need to run at least 4 asynchronous tabs at a time...maybe python is not the right language.

Comment: Depending on your needs there is some sudo asynchronous like process however without knowing exactly what it is you need to accomplish I cant say for sure if python will work for you in this case.

Comment: I'm reading [modbus](https://www.csimn.com/CSI_pages/Modbus101.html) information from multiple slave devices and writing to their registries using a python GUI. So each tab would be one connection to a modbus device.

Comment: Hum. There may be some useful information [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing). Is there a reason why you must read/write with 4 parallel processes being synchronized?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145991/discussion-between-evan-and-sierra-mountain-tech).